# How Can I display a event when the user keep touch in a Listview?

Tags: android

I have seen in app that When the user keep the touch in a listview show the action to delete or to do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For when the user keep the touch you can use the listener onItemLongClick
you would have something like this:

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int pos, long id) {
            // show your action.
        }
    });
```